# Check out backend issue in mysql

Tags: php

Hi everyone i need a help. Actually, i am developing an eCommerce website. I have a confusion, is this a correct way or not? Now come to the point. 1st point : Customers visit the site and add some products into the cart. 2nd point : Click on checkout link if he already logged-in. Then he will go to thanks page(this is your order number, total price, etc).

for all these processes, this is my code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"]))
{
header("location:order_login.php");
}
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
$id=$_SESSION["id"];
$email=$_SESSION["email"];
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$contact=$_SESSION["contact"];
$mysqli->query("insert into orders(user_id,user_name,contact_no,email)values('$id','$name','$contact','$email')");

$result=$mysqli->query("select order_id from orders where user_id='$id'  ORDER BY order_id desc limit 1"); 
$obj=$result->fetch_object();
$order_id=$obj->order_id;


}
?>
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <?php
            //Display of cart

            if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
            {
                $total = 0;
                $qty=0;
                ?>



            <?php   
            foreach ($_SESSION["products"] as $cart_itm)
            {   
                $product_qty = $cart_itm["qty"];
                $product_code=$cart_itm["product_code"];
                $image=$cart_itm["pic"];
                $product_name=$cart_itm["name"];

                echo '<img src="../image/product/'.$image.'"width="120px" height="94px">';
                echo 'ucwords($product_name)';
                echo 'ucwords($product_code)';
                echo 'ucwords($product_qty)';
                $subtotal = ($cart_itm["price"]*$product_qty);
                $total = ($total + $subtotal);          
                echo '$subtotal';
                $qty=($product_qty+$qty);

                $mysqli->query("insert into order_details(user_id,img,product_name,product_code,qty,sub_total,order_id)values('$id','$image','$product_name','$product_code','$product_qty','$subtotal',$order_id)");


                }
                ?>






  </form>
```

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question than "Is this the correct way?" Is it working, or isn't it? What problem are you worried about? If you just want people to look at your code and suggest improvements, codereview.stackexchange.com may be a better site.

Comment: HI Barmar i have a problem i am not able to insert total price into order table ?